# htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/files/domain.com/public_html/images/' is executable

Tags: linux, apache, security, permissions, nginx

Today i migrated my images from one server to another and faced a strange permission issue

```
[Mon Mar 25 08:42:23.676315 2013] [core:crit] [pid 15182] (13)Permission denied: [client 24.14.2.22:48113] AH00529: /files/domain.com/public_html/images/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/files/domain.com/public_html/images/' is executable, referer: http://domain.com.com/file.php
```

what i've tried:

```
    chmod -R 777 root_dir
    restorecon -r
    disable selinux
    Chown -R root:root root_dir
```

Comment: that was a bug in aufs, some disks had wrong permissions.

Comment: you need all of the parent directories are readable from the web server's user, in addition to the root directory itself.

Comment: chmod -R 777 is a very dangerous thing to do. It makes every directory and file world writable and executable. If you want to make every file underneath root_dir world readable and every dir under root_dir world executable (so everyone, including the web server, can access a file if the name is known), a safer alternative would be

`find root_dir -type f -print0|xargs -0 chmod o+r`; `find root_dir -type d -print0|xargs -0 chmod o+x`

Substitute o+rx if you want the world to be able to do an `ls` or `readdir` on every directory.

Answer (score 32):

Today I faced this problem. I transferred public_html from the old drive to new one and chown like this:

```
chown -R owner:owner public_html
```

This is correct for sub directories and files inside public_html, but the user of public_html must be nobody so apache can check it's content, so this solved my problem:

```
chown owner:nobody public_html
```

Note: **owner** is the user (for example web1)

Comment: The situation is similar in Plesk: `/var/www/vhosts/example.com` folder must be owned by `user:psaserv`, but everything in it by `user:psacln`.

Comment: links to documentation? This doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Wouldn't this make it so that only root can modify the folder?

Comment: Halil Özgür your suggestion about Plesk saved my day after moving all files and folders from httpsdocs to httpdocs (and switching of compatibility in the relevant Plesk Obsidian account).

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. For me, it's a problem of SeLinux (CentOS 7).

It works for me:

```
$ setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs true
$ chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/
```

Note that you should change the above `/var/www/html/` to an appropriate directory.

Comment: This helped me a lot getting Laravel working on CentOS 7 (LAMP). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I was using Plesk onyx and I got the same error message, I just changed the folder permission to 775 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Other way is

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

[Disable SELinux](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/)

I hope this works for you

Comment: This is an unsecure TEMPORAY WORKAROUND only. After a reboot, the change is gone. Also, it is not a good solution to just turn off security. Better find the real problem and fix it properly. IF you give such an answer, please point out these caveats and if it is a workaround or a solution.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /var{,/services{,/web{,/web-folder}}};
find /var/services/web/web-folder -type d -exec sudo chmod a+rx {} +;
```

You need to make certain that the directory, and all of its parent directories, are readable and executable (executability is required to open a directory) by the web server. You can do this by making the web server user the owner and making the user perms (EG: `chown apache <dir>; chmod u+rx <dir>;`), or by a making the group be the web server group a group which includes the web server user and setting the group perms to (EG: `chgrp apache <dir>; chmod g+rx <dir>;`), or by setting the world perms to (EG: `chmod o+rx <dir>;`).

Comment: running `chmod a+x` on the root site folder worked for me on OS X

Answer (score 0):

open your httpd.conf file and change Deny from all to Allow from all on the .htaccess file

## The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being

## viewed by Web clients.

```
<FileMatch "^\.ht">
  Order allow,dey
  Allow from all
</FileMatch>
```

## this solved my problem

Comment: Thanks a lot! However it's `deny` not `dey`.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use bold huge text in this answer?

Comment: Also, this answer is misleading and wrong. It is not necessary to allow access to .htaccess via the web. In fact, it SHOULD be disallowed.

Answer (score -1):

When I checked `httpd/user-error_log`, it gave

```
[Fri Jan 09 18:58:08 2015] [crit] [client 192.168.1.xxx] (13)Permission
denied: /var/services/web/web-folder/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check
htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

chmod 755 is not fixing the problem. Below command is what works for me. I use http since it is the apache user and group used in Synology DSM 5.1-5021

```
  cd /var/services/web
  chown http:http web-folder


 apache httpd.conf @ /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

more details about the new change
[Apache / Webserver limitations in 5.0](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=232&t=79801)

Comment: I didn't get it. Could you please add more details?