# No permissions on htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vagrant

I'm trying to setup a vagrant box with a lamp stack and was mostly successful. However, now I'm stuck with the error "Server unable to read .htaccess file". My setup is a Centos 7 server with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6.

Apparently, this seems to happen a lot as I saw many people ask that question, but here's the thing:

1) All my folders are with 777 permissions
2) AllowOverride all and Require all granted is set on all of my folders
3) Even went so far as to add apache user to root group just to see if it would change something

I basically did everything that was suggested in all of the posts I saw and still, apache can't read the .htaccess file.

In my logs, I see:

```
[Tue Sep 26 15:20:18.178541 2017] [core:crit] [pid 6491:tid 139938095892224] (13)Permission denied: [client 10.0.2.15:52176] AH00529: /var/www/html/Kalendho/public/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/html/Kalendho/public/' is executable
```

So I presume apache actually find the file, but for some reason, cannot open it even though it should be able to. So really, any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm currently at my whit's end here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "All my folders are with 777 permissions" — What about the .htaccess file itself?

Comment: "Even went so far as to add apache user to root group just to see if it would change something" — NEVER do that!

Comment: Try with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607300/htaccess-pcfg-openfile-unable-to-check-htaccess-file-ensure-it-is-readable-and

Comment: htaccess file has 777 permissions and I do know it's a bad idea to set apache user as root, but as i said, I was at my whit's end

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so apparently, it was an issue with selinux. Here's what I did:

Opened the file /etc/selinux/config and changed the following line:

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

to

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

After that, I rebooted my machine and it got rid of the htaccess error.