# CakePHP permission problems

Tags: php, cakephp

Hello anybody can help with that problem on old cake app:

> [Wed Sep 26 18:58:29.454771 2018] [core:crit] [pid 28046:tid       140483665811200] (13)Permission denied: [client 170.231.113.140:34906] AH00529: /home/vtecnet/public_html/admin/app/webroot/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/vtecnet/public_html/admin/app/webroot/' is executable

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/q/15607300/1392379**, **https://stackoverflow.com/q/20627084/1392379**, **https://serverfault.com/q/61726/179606**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before continuing, could you please spend a minute and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly?

Comment: Formatting description to improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the error message is giving you all the information:

> […] ensure [.htaccess] is readable and that '/home/vtecnet/public_html/admin/app/webroot/' is executable

I don’t know which version of CakePHP an *old cake app* is, since you’re not telling us, but looking at file permissions and `chmod` should point you in the right direction.

WordPress has a nice article on permissions: https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Installation-Preparation.html#permissions

Something like this could help you out, if you have shell access to the server:

```
# set the ownership to the webserver user (i. e. www-data)
chown -R <insert_webserver_user_here> /home/vtecnet/public_html/admin/
# set permissions recursively
chmod -R 755 /home/vtecnet/public_html/admin/
```